# How can i adjust joined table query result in needed JSON format with CodeIngiter

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter

Suppose we have table `person` and table `phone`and the relation between them is one to many.

I need to retrieve this like result with one query.

```
[
  {
    name:"abc",
    lname:"def",
    phones:[
        {
        dial_code="+1",
        number:"12345667"
        },
        {
        dial_code="+1",
        number:"12345667"
        }
      ]

  },
  {
    name:"xyz",
    lname:"lmn",
    phones[
       {
       dial_code="+2",
       number:"2643525"
       }
     ]
  },
  {...}

]
```

I can do this by multiple query like first getting all `persons` and then get their `phones` one by one but i think its so weird and need lots of time and reduce performance. and if i get all data by joining table it wouldn't be like this `JSON` format.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: even if you don't have an idea how to do that - @least provide the required data (table relation ids etc.) and try anyway an approach - its really tough to get an answer here if you don't try anything... (u r a member for 2 years now - i guess its reasonable to ask you for that)

Comment: @sintakonte i mention that i did that by first getting all persons and then loop those persons and retrieve phones. i just wants to know if its possible to increase performance by just reduce the number of queries.
I don't know what else data should I provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you cannot retrieve the desired result with multiple `phone` inside each `person` with one single query.

Now, running the query inside `person` loop will hugely affect the performance of the script if there are a lot of data. In this way, first, you need to execute a query to fetch all persons(say `n` persons). Then you have to again loop all `n` persons to fetch their respective phones.
So you need to run something like following inside `$persons` loop `n` times:

```
SELECT * FROM phone WHERE person_id = [$person_id]
```

Therefore in this way you need to execute `n+1` queries.

To overcome this `n+1` query problem we can apply a methodology which is called as `eager loading`. Here you also need to execute the first query to retrieve all persons and then write a query to fetch all phones which belongs to those retrieved persons:

```
SELECT * FROM person
```

Result($persons):

```
id      name
5       John
10      Bob
20      Jenna

SELECT * FROM phone WHERE person_id IN (5,10,20)
```

Result($phones):

```
id    person_id    dial_code   number
1     5            +2          12345
2     10           +1          12312
3     20           +1          98765
```

Now we combine these two results in PHP scripts to produce the desired array. In this way, we write only two queries instead of `n+1` queries.

You can write a PHP script like following to combine the two result sets:

```
// Create an array of phones with person_id as key
$phones_with_person_id_as_key = [];
foreach($phones as $key => $phone) {
    $phones_with_person_id_as_key[$phone->person_id][$key] = $phone;
}

// Loop $persons array and add phones to person object
foreach($persons as $key => $person) {
    // create phones key and add data
    if (!empty($phones_with_person_id_as_key[$person->id])) {
        $person->phones = $phones_with_person_id_as_key[$person->id];
    }
    else {
        $person->phones = [];
    }
}
```

Now `$persons` contains the formatted desired output.

Comment: so you say first i need to get all persons and then retrieve their ids and do another query with IN Clause to get phones and then check which phones are belong to each person ?

Comment: Exactly, you run two queries in total and then write some scripts to prepare the person array with nested phones data in a key.

Comment: Here is a doc link for `Laravel` framework which has the method(with) inbuilt: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading